# Core Plot: Warning that plotPoint:forPlotAreViewPoint: and plotAreViewPointForPlotPoint: are deprecated

Tags: ios, uikit, ios7, core-plot

When compiling Core Plot 1.4 with iOS 7, I get the following warnings:

```
plotPoint:forPlotAreViewPoint: is deprecated
```

and

```
plotAreViewPointForPlotPoint: is deprecated
```

How can I substitute these methods to avoid the warnings?

Answer (score 0):

plotPoint:forPlotAreaViewPoint method will be removed in the 2.0 release. Use this

```
 -plotPoint:numberOfCoordinates:forPlotAreaViewPoint:
```

similarly for  method plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint use below one

```
   -plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:numberOfCoordinates
```

Your can also refer the coreplot documentation
      http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/list